# Retrieve PostgreSQL hash password from Python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, hash, cryptography

I'm missing something somewhere. I have the following Python3 code to insert a user and password

```
INSERT INTO table_name (emailAddress, password) 
    VALUES(%s, crypt(%s, gen_salt('bf'))) 
    ON CONFLICT (emailAddress) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING memberId;
```

This seems to be working fine. It inserts a nice hashed password in the DB but I looked Here(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/pgcrypto.html) and  have the following code to retrieve it:

```
SELECT * from table_name 
    WHERE emailAddress='{email_addy}' 
    AND password=crypt('{password}', '{password}');
```

and obviously the query keeps coming back as nothing. Can someone point me in the direction how I can get the info I want? I'm guessing the hash isn't matching up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the same argument to "crypt" twice.

You instead need to give it the cleartext password, and the hash column.

```
AND password=crypt('{password}', password);
```

Comment: Nice! @jjanes. That was the exact problem. I'll look into it more to make sure I understand how that works actually. Much appreciated.